# cannot save row update in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio

I made a database of a school which contains a bunch of values and I'm trying to make an update function in the program I'm making , whenever I save the changes in the server it gives an Exception, here is a code sample of which how I update the row locally:

```
var query =
    from s in db.Students
    where s.StudentID == querierID
    select s;

foreach (Student s in query)
{
    s.FirstName = fntb.Text;
    s.LastName = lntb.Text;
    s.Mobile = mobiletb.Text;
    s.Street = streettb.Text;
}
```

And here is how I Actually save to the database(Send the updated row to it)

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Please give us exception text at least..

Comment: Invalid Operation Exception . :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [InvalidOperationException when calling SaveChanges in .NET Entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008582/invalidoperationexception-when-calling-savechanges-in-net-entity-framework)

Comment: No its not , in that question he makes a new row and saves it , though in this i update an already existing row. :D

Comment: any content inside Message property?

Comment: There should be more details of the error if you 'view details' when the exception is thrown. We need to know that information too.

Comment: Additional information: The property 'StudentID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. , though I'm not trying to modify StudentID because it is the primary key . :/

Comment: If StudentID is a PK use 'Find' instead of looping.

Answer (score 1):

If `StudentID` is the primary key, you should write your code in a way that it will fail if this logic becomes false.

By using the `Single()` [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) your code will return just a single student or throw if the query returns more results.

This makes your code more readable

```
var studentToEdit = (
    from s in db.Students
    where s.StudentID == querierID
    select s
    ).Single();

studentToEdit.FirstName = fntb.Text;
studentToEdit.LastName = lntb.Text;
studentToEdit.Mobile = mobiletb.Text;
studentToEdit.Street = streettb.Text;

db.SaveChanges();
```

If you had used this approach, you would gotten a more detailed exception, pointing you in the right direction immedialtely.

Writing exactly what you mean, is the most difficult part of programming but has big advantages, like this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , so I found the answer to it , the problem isn't actually what i thought it was , it is that when I Signed QueryID it was like

```
Selectedstudent.StudentID = QueryID
```

Instead of

```
QueryID = Selectedstudent.StudentID
```

I'm really sorry for wasting everyones time , but thank you all for trying to help me. and if anyone has a problem , they better check their code before posting a question and wasting everyones time like I did , really sorry everyone :( .

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct answer if your problem is resolved with this solution.

Comment: I have to wait 1 more day to do so :/